# while loop will not break

Tags: python, list, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a while loop that will not break. I added a redundant conditional to make it break but that didn't work either. It is supposed to loop through a 2d array and see if it can place a block of certain dimension in that spot. Block is a list and box is a 2d list. Here is the entire program. The function in question is fillBox

```
def makeBox(dim):
    box = [[0 for x in range(0, dim)] for y in range(0, dim)]
    return box
def printBox(lst):
    for x in lst:
        print(x)
    print()
def isSpaceFree(box, row, col, block):
    isFree = True
    if block > 1:
        if row+block-1 < len(box) and col+block-1 < len(box):
            for x in range(row,row+block):
                for y in range(col, col+block):
                    if box[x][y] != 0:
                        isFree = False
        else:
            isFree = False
    elif block == 1:
            if box[row][col] == 0:
                isFree = True
            else:
                isFree = False
    return isFree
def fillSpace(block, row, col, box):
    if block > 1:
        for x in range(row, row + block):
            for y in range(col, col + block):
                box[x][y] = block
    if block == 1:
        box[row][col] = block
    printBox(box)
def fillBox(block, box):
    row = 0
    col = 0
    while len(block) > 0:
        if len(block) == 0:
            break
        if row == len(block):
            col = 0
            row = 0
            block.pop(0)
        if col == len(block):
            col = 0
            row += 1
        if isSpaceFree(box, row, col, block[0]):
           fillSpace(block[0], row, col, box)
           block.pop(0)
            row = 0
            col = 0
            continue
        col += 1
def main():
    dim = int(input("Enter box dimension: "))
    file = open(input("Block File: "))
    blocks = []
    for x in file:
        blocks = x.split()
    for x in range(0,len(blocks)):
        blocks[x] = int(blocks[x])
    blocks.sort(reverse=True)
    box = makeBox(dim)
    fillBox(blocks, box)
    printBox(box)
main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! you should attempt to narrow down your question/problem and paste less code

Comment: @CameronSparr He did in another question a couple minutes ago. No idea why he deleted it though.

Comment: I was asked to post more code and I didn't know how much to put in, so I gave it all. It's a loop problem and it wont break. The block list becomes empty and an index out of bounds exception is thrown.

Comment: If you don't have a debugger to single-step through the code, add `print` statements to find out what's happening as the loop goes around.  It's obvious that `block` never becomes empty (why is that obvious? *because* your loop never ends).  Why do you think it *must* become empty?  That's where you'll find the error.

Comment: @TimPeters I did do that and the list is empty.

Comment: @NickJames, so you're telling me that `block` is an empty list but `len(block) > 0` returns `True`.  Then I don't believe you ;-)

Comment: Alright I fixed it. The loop still doesn't break on it's own, but I made it break. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I dunno Nick... I ran your code and got "index out of bounds" errors because of the problem mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

The first conditional in the loop is never triggered.

If the block is *greater than zero* (to continue the loop), it is not ever equal to zero right after.

Comment: I know that it shouldn't be triggered. I threw it in so that if the loop somehow didn't break, that would catch it.

Comment: No, Nick. What he meant was that `len(block) == 0)` never evaluates to true.

Comment: what is an example of the blocks list?

Comment: So what would be a good alternative to loop until the list is empty?

Answer (score 1):

```
   if row == len(block):
        col = 0
        row = 0
        block.pop(0)  # If row == 1 and len(block) == 1 This will pop the last item
    if col == len(block):
        col = 0
        row += 1
    if isSpaceFree(box, row, col, block[0]):  # Then this index will be out of bounds - correct?
```